# Cannot connect to SFP sever using key file with JSch and Java 8

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to connect to a SFTP server using a 2048 bit RSA key file. It works fine running against version 7r45 of the JRE using JSch but i get the follow exception when running against version 8r31 of the JRE.

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 2048 (inclusive).`

It's not an issue with limited Java security policy as I have tried it with and without the unlimited strength jars for both versions of java.

I have seen other references to this exception suggesting replacing the default java JCE provider with the BouncyCastle one, but why would there be a difference between java 7 and java 8? I did try this by running 
`Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` at program start up but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: In a Java 8 environment, I am also running into the same error when invoking an `scp` task (which depends on JSch) from ant. The only minor difference is I am seeing: `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)`

Comment: I've just run across similar behavior, where I connect successfully with a 1024-bit key but fail with a 2048-bit one.  I added debugging to JSCH and was able to determine that the server (which uses a 1024-bit key) was sending me a number of different keys of 2047 bits in length, which the JCE code rejects for not being a multiple of 64.  I don't yet know why, and I haven't tested whether Java 7r45 or later fixes the problem.

Comment: @JulienChastang, your problem appears to be that you're running with Java 1.6 or 1.7, which don't allow 2048-bit keys.  Maybe Ant's invoking tasks using an earlier JRE even though you've got Java 8 on the system?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in our case seems to be fixed/worked around by removing diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 before calling session.connect()

```
String kex = session.getConfig("kex");
System.out.println("old kex:" + kex);
kex = kex.replace(",diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1", "");
session.setConfig("kex", kex);
System.out.println("new kex:" + session.getConfig("kex"));
session.connect();
```

[We control the client, but not the server that we were failing to connect to.]

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved such issue by enabling diffie-hellman-group14 algorithm on SFTP server